# Adding Items to an ICollection in the Datastore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm actually just trying to append some items to an ICollection in my design models.

newItem.EmployeeIds has a list of Ids that work totally fine.

For example:

```
   public class Employee
    {
        public Employee()
        {
            this.Notes = new List<Note>();
            this.DirectReports = new List<Employee>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Employee> DirectReports { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    }
```

I've tried this:

```
public IEnumerable<EmployeeList> ConfigureDirectReports(EmployeeDirectReports newItem)
        {

            var fetchedObject = ds.Employees.Find(newItem.Id);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fetchedObject.DirectReports.Count());

            if (fetchedObject.IdentityUserId == User.Identity.Name)
            {
                ds.Entry(fetchedObject);

                foreach (var item in newItem.EmployeeIds) {
                    fetchedObject.DirectReports.Add(ds.Employees.Find(item));
                }

                ds.SaveChanges();
                return null;

            }
            return null;
        }
```

I'm trying to save a few Employee objects in `DirectReports`.

Comment: What happens when you run this? Does it not save the employees in DirectReports?

Comment: Nope, it does not...